# Inserting a character before specified character in hierarchical manner in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

```
test.dat <- c("abcde", "abcXe", "abcdY", "abcXY", "abYcXY", "abcYX")
test.want <- c("abcde", "abc1Xe", "abcd1Y", "abc1XY", "abYc1XY", "abcY1X")
```

Suppose I wish to add "1" before "X" or "Y", and **only before** "X" if both "X" and "Y" exist.

```
library(tidyverse)
case_when(
  str_detect(test.dat, "X") ~ str_replace(test.dat, "X", "1X"),
  str_detect(test.dat, "Y") ~ str_replace(test.dat, "Y", "1Y"),
  TRUE ~ as.character(test.dat)
)
```

This works but is there a better way to do this in concise manner? Perhaps in single `str_replace`?

How about a second scenario if it was either "X" or "Y" **whichever** comes first?

```
test.dat <- c("abcde", "abcXe", "abcdY", "abcXY", "abYcXY", "abcYX")
test.want <- c("abcde", "abc1Xe", "abcd1Y", "abc1XY", "ab1YcXY", "abc1YX")
```

stringr is preferable but I welcome any other methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a look ahead with `(?=X)` for `X` and `(?=Y)` for `Y` and make the decission if there is an `X` with `ifelse` and `grepl`.

```
test.dat <- c("abcde", "abcXe", "abcdY", "abcXY", "abYcXY", "abcYX", "YXXdY")

ifelse(grepl("X", test.dat)
     , sub("(?=X)", "1", test.dat, perl=TRUE)
     , sub("(?=Y)", "1", test.dat, perl=TRUE))
#[1] "abcde"   "abc1Xe"  "abcd1Y"  "abc1XY"  "abYc1XY" "abcY1X"  "Y1XXdY"
```

or

```
sub("(?=X)|(?=Y(?!.*X))", "1", test.dat, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "abcde"   "abc1Xe"  "abcd1Y"  "abc1XY"  "abYc1XY" "abcY1X"  "Y1XXdY"
```

Where `(?=X)` matches a position before `X` and `(?=Y(?!.*X))` matches a position before `Y` which has no `X` at any position afterwards.

In case not only the first hit should be used:

```
ifelse(grepl("X", test.dat)
     , gsub("(?=X)", "1", test.dat, perl=TRUE)
     , gsub("(?=Y)", "1", test.dat, perl=TRUE))
#[1] "abcde"   "abc1Xe"  "abcd1Y"  "abc1XY"  "abYc1XY" "abcY1X"  "Y1X1XdY"
```

or

```
gsub("(?=X)|(^[^X]*)(?=Y(?!.*X))", "\\11", test.dat, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "abcde"   "abc1Xe"  "abcd1Y"  "abc1XY"  "abYc1XY" "abcY1X"  "Y1X1XdY"
```

And to match `X` or `Y` whichever comes first:

```
sub("(?=X)|(?=Y)", "1", test.dat, perl=TRUE)
#sub("(?=X|Y)", "1", test.dat, perl=TRUE) #Alternative
#sub("(?=[XY])", "1", test.dat, perl=TRUE) #Alternative
#[1] "abcde"   "abc1Xe"  "abcd1Y"  "abc1XY"  "ab1YcXY" "abc1YX"  "1YXXdY"
```

Comment: My understanding is that `(?!.*X`)` serves as a condition to do `(?=Y)` if `*X` is not there.  However, it seems that `sub("(?=X)|(?=Y)", "1", test.dat, perl=TRUE)` returns same result.  Can I safely assume OR statement in regex automatically go from left to right in hierachy or would that assumption be wrong?

Comment: @aiorr  `(?=X)|(?=Y)(?!.*X)` is a pattern that matches either a position right before `X` or right before `Y` that is not followed with any zero or more chars followed with an `X` char.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
test.dat <- c("abcde", "abcXe", "abcdY", "abcXY", "abYcXY", "abcYX")
sub("^([^XY]*)(Y)([^X]*)$|(.*)(X)", "\\1\\41\\3\\5\\2", test.dat)
# => [1] "abcde"   "abc1Xe"  "abcd1Y"  "abc1XY"  "abYc1XY" "abcY1X" 

stringr::str_replace(test.dat, "^([^XY]*)(Y)([^X]*)$|(.*)(X)", "\\1\\41\\3\\5\\2")
# => [1] "abcde"   "abc1Xe"  "abcd1Y"  "abc1XY"  "abYc1XY" "abcY1X"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LHjQ4e/3).

Here,

- `^([^XY]*)(Y)([^X]*)$` - start of string (`^`), Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `X` and `Y` (`([^XY]*)`), Group 2: `Y` (`(Y)`), Group 3: any zero or more chars other than `X` (`([^X]*)`), end of string (`$`)
- `|` - or
- `(.*)` - Group 4: any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `(X)` - Group 5: `X` char.

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/4KHkZy).

If you need to add 1 to the end of strings not having `X` or `Y`:

```
test.dat <- c("abcde", "abcXe", "abcdY", "abcXY", "abYcXY", "abcYX")
sub("^([^XY]*)$", "\\11", sub("^([^XY]*)(Y)([^X]*)$|(.*)(X)", "\\1\\41\\3\\5\\2", test.dat))
 
library(stringr)
str_replace(str_replace(test.dat, "^([^XY]*)(Y)([^X]*)$|(.*)(X)", "\\1\\41\\3\\5\\2"), "^([^XY]*)$", "\\11")
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/2CNwvc). Output:

```
[1] "abcde1"  "abc1Xe"  "abcd1Y"  "abc1XY"  "abYc1XY" "abcY1X"
```

Comment: your solution cause `abcYX` to be `abc1Y1X`.  I wish to add "1" before "X" or "Y", and only before "X" if both "X" and "Y" exist.   I should've added "abcYX" to the `test.dat`, I apologize.  Would you possibly have another solution? Thank you.

Comment: I would like `abcYX` to be `abcY1X`, since I want to add only before "X" if both "X" and "Y" exists.  

However, my second part of my question was "How about if it was either "X" or "Y" whichever comes first?", so the solution for `abc1YX` is valid as well, although I would prefer answer to both parts so I can compare them side to side :)